# Como executar um metodo em tempo determinado?

Tags: android, android-service

Preciso que em determinadas horas programadas, seja executado um método mesmo o usuário estando fora da aplicação.Pelo que pesquisei vou ter que utilizar serviços?
Não entendi muito bem como programa o tempo, apenas deixei a classe criada aqui:

```
public class Notificacao extends Service {


public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();

}

@Override

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    //fez_algo

    Toast.makeText(Notificacao.this, "Fez algo", 1000).show();
    return START_STICKY;

}
```

Mas como executar um método , a cada 1 hora por exemplo? esse método pode ser declarado na mesma classe do serviço, alguém me diz a forma mais simples?

Comment: Tens de ter um Thread a correr que vá vendo se já está na hora e quando estiver fazer o que pretendes.

Comment: @JorgeB. isso não poderia sobrecarregar o sistema caso por exemplo eu queira atualizar um contador a cada 1s? Digamos, mostrar uma contagem regressiva na barra de notificações para quando passar 1h executar alguma coisa. PS: eu não sei a resposta, não estou te criticando, só quero saber os efeitos da sua solução.

Comment: @Math é assim que funcionam os alarmes e calendários. Não tens outra forma de saber que já passou uma hora. Tem mesmo de ser ao segundo.

Comment: Para quê criar um Thread ou um novo serviço se o SO Android tem um que, de forma nativa, faz isso: [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use um `BroadcastReceiver` juntamente com `AlarmManager`.
No método `onReceive`do `BroadcastReceiver` mande executar a tarefa programada.

```
public class ExecutarTarefaProgramadaReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //      Código a executar
    }

}
```

Para iniciar o processo utilize este código:

```
//Definir a hora de início
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Intent tarefaIntent = new Intent(context, ExecutarTarefaProgramadaReceiver.class);
PendingIntent tarefaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,1234, tarefaIntent,0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

//Definir o alarme para acontecer todos os dias às 10 horas
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                 AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, tarefaPendingIntent);
```

Não esquecer de registar o `BroadcastReceiver` no *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<receiver android:name="a_sua_package.ExecutarTarefaProgramadaReceiver"/>
```

Veja a documentação do [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) para saber como definir outros intervalos de tempo.

Para executar 4x por dia(de 6 em 6 horas), a começar às 10 horas:

```
//Definir início para as 10 horas
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

//Definir intervalo de 6 horas
long intervalo = 6*60*60*1000; //6 horas em milissegundos

Intent tarefaIntent = new Intent(context, ExecutarTarefaProgramadaReceiver.class);
PendingIntent tarefaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,1234, tarefaIntent,0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

//Definir o alarme para acontecer de 6 em 6 horas a partir das 10 horas
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                 intervalo, tarefaPendingIntent);
```

Se a tarefa a executar for demorada, em vez de um Boadccast receiver use um serviço para executá-la.
Esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/189288/2541) mostra uma possível implementação.
O codigo a executar deve ser colocado no método `onHandleIntent()`.
A implementação lida com a situação do dispositivo ser desligado, resgistando novamente a tarefa ao ser ligado.

Comment: Pra que serve o BroadcastReceiver? Estou perguntando pois não sei mesmo, e como eu tenho interesse na resposta gostaria de saber um pouco mais do jeito indicado pela sua resposta para eu poder avaliar prós e contras dela.

Comment: É na classe *ExecutarTarefaProgramadaReceiver*, que deriva de *BroadcastReceiver*, onde você coloca o código que quer que seja executado na hora que você definir no *AlarmManager*. No exemplo que dei, o *AlarmManager* irá "instanciar" a classe *ExecutarTarefaProgramadaReceiver* e chamar o método *onReceive* todos os dias às 10 horas. Isto acontece mesmo que a aplicação, que definiu o *BroadcastReceiver* e iniciou o *AlarmManager*, não esteja em execução.

Comment: O [*BroadcastReceiver*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) é uma classe que o Android utiliza para receber *Intents*. Quando é enviado um [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) o Android informa todos os *"Receivers"* registados para que eles o possam processar

Comment: Olá, funcionou muito obrigado. mas como faço para executar 4 x por dia?

Comment: De uma olhada na documentação, mais especificamente no método `setRepeating` do `AlarmManager`. E de uma olhada na nota sobre o comportamento do Alarme no KitKat.

Comment: Actualizei resposta com código para 4x por dia

Comment: ramaral, obrigado voce é o cara.So tenho uma duvida, percebi que ele ta fazendo a verificação, quando rodo a aplicação apos a hora programada. Ex programei pra 5h, se eu abrir o app 5:05 ele ta fazendo o metodo... é assim mesmo ou tem algo errado?

Comment: Sim, é assim mesmo. Você não deve utilizar os comentários para agradecer. Veja neste link http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers a forma correta de como agradecer quando uma resposta lhe é útil.

Comment: Recomendaria também dar uma olhada na [Android-Job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) da evernote, ele faz todo o grosso trabalho de criar os managers, receivers e tauz, e também faz persistencia de jobs, execução somente se certas caracteristicas estiverem disponiveis e tauz. E também trata as diferentes apis do android com seus diversos métodos.

Comment: @ramaral esta seria a forma de executar um método com o APP fechado tanto da tela, quanto da lista de tarefas ?

Comment: Sim. O BroadcastReceveir será chamado mesmo quando a aplicação não está em execução.