# Aplicativo é fechado depois de um tempo, mesmo com serviço

Tags: android

Olá tenho um serviço que roda em background, esse serviço não deveria ser finalizado pelo sistema do Android, porém acontece isso depois de um tempo de execução.

```
public class VerificaCorridas extends Service {

private Timer timerAskServer;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    verifyServer();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    timerAskServer.cancel();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public void verifyServer() {
    timerAskServer = new Timer();
    TimerTask askServer = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            // Aqui é feito uma consulta ao servidor para ver se tem algo novo
        };

    };
    timerAskServer.schedule(askServer, 0, 10000); //repete a cada 10 Seg
}
```

}

Comment: Sem conhecer o código do serviço fica difícil.

Comment: Irei tentar reduzir o código para postar, mas pode acontecer isso? Um serviço ele ser finalizado pelo sistema?

Comment: Pode, depende da forma como ele é declarado.

Comment: Pronto postei o código

Comment: Para esse caso especifico e se não quiser usar o *Google cloud messaging (GCM)* use um *AlarmManager* com um *BroadcastReceiver*. Veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/26275/2541) um exemplo.

Comment: @MateusCarvalho este APP que você está elaborando é para Entregas Rápidas?

Comment: Não @AndréBaill

Comment: @ramaral eu uso o parse.com, nele já está incluído o serviço do GCM, porém há um delay de tempo ás vezes na entrega da mensagem... Isso não pode acontecer, sabe dizer se é normal?

Comment: Não sei, nunca utilizei o *Parse*.

Answer (score 0):

Falando muito genericamente, qualquer serviço do Android pode ser interrompido a qualquer momento, em particular se o celular tiver pouca memória. É assim que a plataforma funciona.

Uma alternativa para garantir que ele volte depois de uma interrupção, é reiniciá-lo periodicamente com um Alarm.

Outra alternativa, bastante intrusiva, é iniciar o serviço com [startForeground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)). Nesta modalidade uma notificação fica permanentemente na área de notificações (ela não pode ser "dismissed" pelo usuário) o que "segura" o serviço na memória.

Serviços que gastem recursos e rodam o tempo todo devem usar esta solução, segundo as UI Guidelines do Android. Por exemplo: um aplicativo de música, que está usando áudio o tempo todo e não deveria ser interrompido.

Dito isto, um serviço com notificação permanente AINDA pode ser parado em caso de absoluta falta de memória. Então o Alarm ainda é necessário se você quer garantir que ele vai rodar 24x7.

Answer (score 0):

Como desenvolvedor Android é importante ter em mente que você não possui controle sobre o ciclo de vida de uma aplicação. A qualquer momento o seu dispositivo pode ficar sem recursos (acabar a memória, por exemplo) e o sistema irá finalizar o aplicativo para dar manter o OS rodando corretamente.

Esse comportamento é valido para qualquer parte de sua aplicação. Dessa forma, você precisa utilizar um `AlarmManager` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) para disparar periodicamente o seu serviço e fazer a verificação. Não é legal manter um serviço rodando eternamente, para não ser intrusivo e consumir recursos desnecessário do usuário.