# Como identificar alteração do estado de conetividade à Internet para executar um método ao conetar?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Eu estou tentando implementar esse trem e não to conseguindo. Eu queria fazer a mesma coisa que o colega que abriu o tópico, mas não consegui nem seguindo esses exemplos.

Tenho algumas dúvidas: Em que classe eu defino esse lance do Calendar? No receiver mesmo? pelo que eu entendi do exemplo, ele está chamando ele próprio nesse exemplo do tópico([link do tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26264/como-executar-um-metodo-em-tempo-determinado/88552#88552)):

```
Intent tarefaIntent = new Intent(context, ExecutarTarefaProgramadaReceiver.class);
```

O que eu gostaria: Estou desenvolvendo em conjunto com colegas da facul, um sisteminha de localização. A ideia é verificar de tempos em tempos se existe uma conexão com a internet. Se tiver conexão e informações da nossa app não enviadas, então enviaremos os dados para um webservice ou qualquer outro lugar que imaginarmos. Dessa forma que eu fiz, cada vez que eu desbloqueio a tela do celular ele apenas abre o mapa. (mas não é isso que eu quero, pois quero que o serviço permaneça ativo e ao "acordar(verifica uma condição e se for verdadeira executa)" execute um método).

Resumo:

Eu gostaria que o meu serviço fosse iniciado no boot do celular e ficasse "ouvindo" até que haja uma conexão com a internet. Quando houver, então faz alguma coisa - nesse caso, executa um método que eu determinar (que também não sei onde deve ficar).

Minha Receive:

```
package com.teste.receiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.teste.MapsActivity;

/**
 * Created by Jaquisson on 17/09/2015.
 */
public class TbReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);


        }
    }

}
```

MeuService está assim:

```
package com.teste.service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

/**
 * Created by Jaquisson-SENAC on 17/09/2015.
 */
public class TbService extends Service {
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        //IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        //filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        //filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);

        //receiver = new TbReceiver();

        //Log.d("service", "Receiver será iniciado");
        //registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

        //super.onCreate();

    }


}
```

E abaixo o trecho do meu manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".service.TbService"
    android:exported="false" >
</service>
<service
    android:name=".BuscaLocalizacao"
    android:exported="false" >
</service>

<receiver  android:name=".receiver.TbReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Cara, já pesquisei em vários lugares e não consigo entender como devo fazer. Olhei na documentação, mas também não entendi. Estou iniciando e um pouco perdido nisso.

Me desculpem postar esse monte de coisa, mas eu sou meio detalhista.

Obrigado.

Comment: Eu já fiz algo similar e utilizei o design pattern Observer, terá que criar uma classe que será atualizada toda vez que não houver conexão com internet ou vice-versa. Algo desse tipo de implementação : http://www.devmedia.com.br/padrao-de-projeto-observer-em-java/26163

Answer (score 3):

Você pode adicionar na sua classe tbReceiver um método para verificar a conexão da seguinte forma:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvaliable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

e no seu mainfest deve ter essa permissão:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Aí é só você verificar se tem conexão com um if:

```
if(isNetworkAvaliable()){
   //seu código aqui
}
```

Comment: não consegui fazer dessa forma. Na verdade até consegui, mas não funcionou. Enquanto "aguardo" mais sugestões, vou continuar procurando na internet. Se eu achar algo eu posto aqui. Se alguém tiver mais alguma dica eu agradeço.

Answer (score 2):

Para ser notificado aquando de uma alteração do estado de conectividade à rede(*network*) deverá declarar um *BroadcastReceveir* que responda à *Action* `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`

---

No AndroidManifest.xml registe o *BroadcastReceveir*: (Ver nota)

```
<receiver android:name=".ConnectivityChangeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

---

O *BroadcastReceveir* será qualquer coisa do género:

```
public class ConnectivityChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
            if(isConnected(ctx)){
                //O código aqui é executado ao conectar
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Conectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                //O código aqui é executado ao desconectar
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Desconectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) 
                    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
             }
         }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Inclua esta permissão no *manifest*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Tenha em conta que ter uma ligação activa à rede não garante que tenha acesso à internet, veja [Teste de conexão com internet eficaz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/197035/2541).

### Nota:

BroadcastReceiver's de aplicações com `targetSdkVersion` igual ou superior à API Level 24(Android 7) não receberão esta notificação se declarados no AndroidManifest.xml.

O seu registo tem de ser feito de forma explicita usando [Context.registerReceiver()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter)).

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
connectivityChangeReceiver = new ConnectivityChangeReceiver();
registerReceiver(connectivityChangeReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Comment: Boa noite! Não funcionou. Não acontece nada. Eu implementei dessa forma, desativo ou ativo a internet e simplesmente nada acontece.

Comment: Em `<receiver android:name=".ConnectivityChangeReceiver">` faltava o`.` antes do nome da classe, não esqueça de incluir a permissão.

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia Pessoal!
São 2:30 da matina e consegui entender essa bagaça (não sei se com a melhor prática, mas funcionou).
Primeiramente, não sei se está certo eu mesmo responder a minha pergunta. Se não estiver eu corrijo.

Bom, vamos lá:
Primeiramente, tentei utilizar o NetworkInfo[], mas parece que não se utiliza mais.

Fica difícil colocar os créditos da solução que eu implementei, pois fui atrás de muita coisa e fui entendendo como as coisas funcionavam.

Bom, para resumir eu entendi que o que eu precisava inicialmente era apenas do BroadcastReceiver, pois é ele quem vai ficar "escutando" o evento que vai fazer ele estartar o meu método:

```
package com.teste.receiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;

public class TbReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean conectado;

        ConnectivityManager conectivtyManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            conectado = true; //Aqui chamo o serviço que envia dados, por exemplo



        } else {
            conectado = false; //não faço nada, ou faço, não decidi ainda. (risos).
        }

    }
}
```

Meu manifest (apenas o trecho ref. ao BCR:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.TbReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

                <action android:name="DISPARA_EVENTO_X" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

E por fim, o método que coloquei na minha Activity para chamar (quer dizer, passar uma mensagem, segundo meu professor) para criar um AlarmManager do meu BroadcastReceiver:

```
public void chamarBroadcastReceiver(){

    boolean alarmeAtivo = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("DISPARA_EVENTO_X"), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null);

    if(alarmeAtivo){

        Intent intent = new Intent("DISPARA_EVENTO_X");
        PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 3);

        AlarmManager alarme = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarme.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 5000, p);
    }
    else{
        onDestroy(); // chama o método onDestroy @Override da minha Activity
    }

}
```

Bom, espero que não esteja de todo o ruim, pois como falei no inicio, estou aprendendo java e desenvolvimento mobile.

Grande abraço.

Comment: Olha cara testei o seu codigo n funcionou aqui nao

Answer (score 1):

Então, a resposta de @Luiz dev não está completa, pois ela verifica se EXISTE CONECTIVIDADE(Rede WIFI CONECTADA ou 3G), mas isso não quer dizer que você esteja conectado na internet. Para que você possa detectar, você deve enviar algum pacote ou um ping para algum serviço.

Sugestão:

1. Faça a verificação de luiz.
2. Se estiver com conectividade, tente enviar o pacote.
3. Se Retornar Status OK, significa que ele enviou corretamente a

Boa sorte!