# Abrir página web após conectar ao WiFi (mobile)

Tags: mobile, autenticação, navegador-de-internet

Existe uma maneira de forçar o dispositivo mobile a abrir uma página web depois de conectar no `WiFi`?

Não se trata exatamente de um `HotSpot` (autenticação via *landing page*).

**Exemplo:** após conectar em uma rede X (pública) do `WiFi`, o browser seja aberto automaticamente no dispositivo `mobile` e abra uma endereço pré determinado.

Isso é possível?

**Edit:** em todos os sistemas operacionais mobile (Android, iOS, WP e BB).

Comment: Android, IPhone ou WindowsPhone?

Comment: Todas os sistemas operacionais, se possível.

Comment: Isso torna a pergunta ampla. Em android é possível ser notificado quando o dispositivo estabelece uma ligação WiFI, veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88587/2541)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Eu tinha imaginado algo mais genérico que possa ser configurável diretamente na rede, não sei.