# Checar Internet Android

Tags: java, android

Para checar a conexão com a internet fiz o seguinte método.

```
public class ChecaInternet extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    boolean success = false;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
        connection.connect();
        success = connection.getResponseCode() == 204 && connection.getContentLength() == 0;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("IOEx", "Não Há Conexão!!!");
    }
    return success;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    Log.i("POST", "onPostExecute: "+result);
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
}
```

- Caso alguns não saibam, eu execute isso em uma AsyncTask pelo fato de que se fosse executada na Thread principal você receberá uma exceção NetworkOnMainThread.

Caso eu acesse o aplicativo sem internet tudo bem, ele retorna false.
Mas se acesso o aplicativo já conectado e depois desligo o wi-fi o método não retorna false. Ele meio que trava e não retorna nada, já depurei e não há error, apenas é como se a execução travasse e é encerrada a AsyncTask.  Alguém sabe o problema que está acontecendo aqui?

Eu chamo esse metodo da seguinte forma em uma Activity:

```java
public class TelaCadastroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnSave;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_cadastro);

        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCadastrar);

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                new ChecaInternet().execute();
                Toast.makeText(TelaCadastroActivity.this, "Tem conexão? ",          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Relacionado: [Teste de conexão com internet eficaz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/197035/2541) e [Como implementar um serviço que executa um método ao identificar que existe conexão com a internet](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88585/2541)

Answer (score 0):

Eu tenho uma aplicação de wallpapers nessa aplicação ela precisa de verificar a internet para que os wallpapers baixem, talvez o método que eu fiz possa te ajudar de uma olhada:

```
private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {

boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

for (NetworkInfo ni : ((ConnectivityManager) this.context.getSystemService("connectivity")).getAllNetworkInfo()) {
if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI") && ni.isConnected()) {
haveConnectedWifi = true;
        }

if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE") && ni.isConnected()) {
haveConnectedMobile = true;
            }
        }
    if (haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile) {

    return true;
        }
    return false;

}
```

Esse metódo ajuda muito aqui, ele verifica se há alguma conexão seja wifi ou rede movél, se retorna true, ele baixa o wallpaper no caso da minha aplicação.

Comment: Rogers, testei sua solução e funciona para alguns casos, por exemplo, a função que eu coloquei na pergunta ela identifica se há conexão e se a mesma está funcionando, pelo que vi a sua verifica se a conexão esta ativa. No meu caso eu preciso de algo que verifique se tem conexão e se está funcionando.

Comment: a um tempo atrás procurei por algo parecido mas também não encontrava ou quando achava algo não funcionava do modo correto, por isso postei essa. :/ espero que consiga resolver, irei acompanhar esse tópico.

Comment: Encontrei a solução em uma outra função, se quiser eu te passo já testei e funciona perfeitamente, mas queria muito entender o problema dessa, tem coisas que quando os outros fazem funcionam hahaha, saca essa resposta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493517/detect-if-android-device-has-internet-connection/6493572#42018966

Comment: se possível passa ai :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493517/detect-if-android-device-has-internet-connection/6493572#42018966

Answer (score -1):

```
public  boolean verificaConexao() {
        boolean conectado;
        ConnectivityManager conectivtyManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        conectado = true;
        } else {
        conectado = false;
    }
return conectado;
}
```