# Mostar imagem caso esteja sem conexao com a internet

Tags: android, conexão, app, linha-de-comando, internet

Mostrar uma imagem caso o dispositivo esteja sem conexao com internet

Boa tarde senhores sou novo em programação Android, estou usando o Android Studio

Seguinte estou desenvolvendo um app que simplesmente chama um webVier, que direciona para meu site, e gostaria de saber como fazer com que se o celular estiver sem conexao com a internet em vez de chamar o webvier ele abra uma imagem.
meu codigo no manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

e estou usando aqui no Main activy

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private WebView delivery;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    leve=findViewById(R.id.site);
    leve.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    leve.setFocusable(true);
    leve.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    leve.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    leve.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    leve.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    leve.loadUrl("https://meusite.com.br");
}
```

}

Espero que tenha sido claro Obrigado por enquanto

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como identificar alteração do estado de conetividade à Internet para executar um método ao conetar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88569/como-identificar-altera%c3%a7%c3%a3o-do-estado-de-conetividade-%c3%a0-internet-para-executar-um)

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção, seria na sua activity fazer un check para ver se tem internet([google example](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-status-type)) e caso não tenha, ao invés de inserir uma imagem na webView, eu usaria um ImageView com a sua imagem de problema de conexão(ou com outra coisa que queira mostrar) e controlaria a visibilidade de um e de outro com base na conexão. Se tenho conexão Webview.visibility = true (posso deixar o ImagemView por default in false) se não tenho conexão faz Webview.visibility = false e ImageView.visibility = true