# Manter CountDownTimer rodando após o app ser fechado

Tags: android

Fiz um countdown em um service, ele funciona quando o app é mandando pra background, porem quando o app para o estado "dead" ele para a contagem e reinicia quando eu abro novamente. Eu preciso que ele continue funcionando mesmo no estado morto, pois preciso enviar notificações quando um certo tempo chegar por exemplo.
O código que estou tendo esse resultado:
BroadcastService.java

```
package com.example.igord.myapplication2;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by igord on 19/09/2017.
 */

public class BroadcastService extends Service {
    private final static String TAG = "BroadcastService";

    public static final String COUNTDOWN_BR = "com.example.igord.myapplication2";
    Intent bi = new Intent(COUNTDOWN_BR);

    CountDownTimer cdt = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.i(TAG, "Starting timer...");

        cdt = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                Log.i(TAG, "Countdown seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                bi.putExtra("countdown", millisUntilFinished);
                sendBroadcast(bi);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Timer finished");
            }
        };

        cdt.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        cdt.cancel();
        Log.i(TAG, "Timer cancelled");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_NOT_STICKY;

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
package com.example.igord.myapplication2;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "igr";
    private TextView texttempo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startService(new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class));
        Log.i(TAG, "Started service");
        texttempo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_tempo);

    }

    private BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateGUI(intent); // or whatever method used to update your GUI fields
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(BroadcastService.COUNTDOWN_BR));
        Log.i(TAG, "Registered broacast receiver");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(br);
        Log.i(TAG, "Unregistered broacast receiver");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(br);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Receiver was probably already stopped in onPause()
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class));
        Log.i(TAG, "Stopped service");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void updateGUI(Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            long millisUntilFinished = intent.getLongExtra("countdown", 0);
            Log.i(TAG, "Countdown seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            texttempo.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Penso que essa não seja a melhor abordagem. Veja [Como executar um metodo em tempo determinado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/26264/2541)

Comment: Cara, acho que o melhor jeito de você fazer isso seria pela diferença de tempo, por exemplo quando seu app chegar no estado de "stop" ele grava o tempo atual com sharedpreferences, depois quando você abrir o aplicativo, você pega o tempo atual e tira a diferença

Comment: @ramaral eu preciso do countdown rodando tambem na Ui, por isso pensei desta forma, não é só pra notificacao.

Comment: @Matheus Atualmente esta assim, mas quero manter rodando pois preciso enviar notificação quando tiver faltando por exemplo 3 horas para acabar

Comment: Certo, então isso tem que ser função de um backend @IgorOliveira, um serviço rodando ou algo assim que envie essas notificações, pois se matar o processo do app, como ele irá continuar processando ? hehe

Comment: Como disse acima, eu não uso apenas pra enviar notificação, existe um contador na UI do app. então seria interessante manter rodando, pois dai eu posso retirar esse calculo quando o app é aberto novamente ( que esta me dando alguns bugs estranhos). Eu vi que é possivel fazer com broadcast receiver mas não conseguir implementar.

Comment: Opa Igor, tudo certo? Eu fiz um projeto meu, onde eu tenho uma abordagem bem parecida. Eu programo um Alarm Manager, mas tenho um contador na notification e na UI. Como fiz? Foi meio porco na epoca, pois tava começando no Android, mas eu criei um `Service` pra rodar o contador na notification e, assim, tinha lá o tempo sempre armazenado. Assim, quando eu abria a Activity novamente já tinha o contador rodando na minha notification. Ficou assim https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbm6XSLNFHg

Comment: @LMaker é mais ou menos oque quero, porem não tenho interesse em ter sempre a notificacao rodando, só na Ui do app mesmo.

Comment: Consegui, porem ainda não funciona quando eu reinicio o celular

Comment: Se puderam me ajudar aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239318/manter-servi%C3%A7o-quando-o-celular-reiniciar

Comment: A notification dei como exemplo, acho que a abordagem continua a mesma. Rodar no service um contdown