# Atualizar periodicamente a localização quando aplicativo estiver rodando em segundo plano

Tags: android, geolocalização, services, background

Tenho um aplicativo que deve salvar a localização do usuário a cada 1 minuto. Criei um serviço rodando em background que faz isso. Enquanto a tela está ligada e a aplicação está em primeiro plano, funciona perfeitamente. Porém caso vá para segundo plano, a aplicação para de salvar. Li que teve uma atualização no android 8  que limita a chamada de geolocalização quando o aplicativo está em segundo plano. Existe alguma maneira de eu poder continuar salvando a localização com a periodicidade de 1 minuto mesmo o aplicativo estando em segundo plano ou a tela estando desligada?

Answer (score 0):

Isso tem a ver com as [limitações impostas pelo Android 8 à execução de serviços em *background*](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services).

A solução passa por usar um *foreground service*(`startForegroundService()` em vez de `startService()`, ou um *scheduled job* como o [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) incluido no [Android Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/).

Note que o WorkManager não lança as tarefas em tempo exacto, se necessita exactamente de um minuto de intervalo terá de usar um AlarmManager e um BroadcastReceiver.
Veja [Como executar um método em tempo determinado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/26264/2541).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, testei aqui e até salvou, porém muito poucas vezes, não respeitando a periodicidade. Existe alguma maneira de realmente salvar de 1 e 1 minuto?

Comment: Testou usando o quê?

Comment: startForegroundService e schedule task, ambos funcionam mas parcialmente, até chamam, mas não na exata frequência que eu quero